# Настройка красивых url и страницы 404 в apache

Tags: apache, url, http-status-code-404

Всем привет. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как лучше настроить красоту в url и страницу 404
У меня сейчас в apache так

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

А в index.php проверяю $_GET['p'] и выдаю нужную страницу

```
switch ($_GET['p']) {
        case '/':
            require 'templates/main.php';
            break;
        case 'uslugi':
            require 'templates/services_and_tariffs.php';
            break;
...
        и т.д.
...
        default :
           header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
```

Но, в таком случае, не будет срабатывать директива apache

```
ErrorDocument 404 /templates/404.html
```

Если в index.php в default: добавить заголовок

```
header('Location: templates/404.html');
```

То все вроде работает, но заголовки отправляются не те, что нужно, при показе страницы 404

```
мой_сайт/jklsldj - 302
404.html - 200
```

Подскажите, возможно ли сделать, чтоб при заходе на несуществующую страницу отдавался заголовок 404 но при этом показывалась страница 404.html или всю структуру мою изменять надо?
Предвосхищая вопрос, почему не оставить как есть, отвечу так - я не знаю, правильно ли это. В интернетах пишут, что для поисковиков лучше, когда нет редиректа, если страницы не существует, вот я и загнался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это конечно плохое решение, т.к. 404 ошибка с обработкой на php создает лишнюю нагрузку, но вам ведь просто достаточно вывести контент после заголовка:

```
default :
       header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
       include 'templates/404.html';
```

И никогда не отдавайте 404.html через редирект. Для поисковиков это очень плохо + для все клиентов то же, т.к. ошибка понятна только пользователю по тексту на странице, а для всех это 200 ОК

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Как я сам не додумался )))