# Присвоить странице статус 404

Tags: php, http, http-status-code-404

Имеется страница articles.php, на которой по id, указанному в get-запросе, подгружается необходимая статья из БД. Но проблема в том, что в Я.Вебмастере показывает кучу ненужных статей, вызванных периодической сменой идентификаторов у статей. Вопрос, как с помощью средств php присвоить странице статус 404, если статьи с текущим id нет?
Я пробовал делать header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"); но при этом он показывает что страница недоступна, но показывает это штатно, средствами браузера, а не с помощью заданой мной страницы 404 через .htassec (хотя она работает, если просто ввести www.мойсайт.ru/какая-то-муть то он кинет на нужную страницу 404). И в Вебмастере страница которым я присвоил таким образом статус тоже не исчезают, а просто меняют статус на 302. А мне надо чтоб несуществующие статьи пропали из индекса и при переходе на них открывалась нужная страница с ошибкой.
П.С. движок писал сам

Comment: Видимо вам нужно решение из этого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451528/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85-url-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-404-%d0%b2-apache

Answer (score 1):

Если URL-адреса статей перестают быть актуальными из-за смены ID статей, то лучше, вместо страницы ошибки, делать 301-й редирект (т.е. перемещено навсегда) на новый адрес.

На PHP это можно сделать, например, так:

```
$urls_for_redirect = array(
  '/page/OLD_ID' => '/page/NEW_ID'
);
if ( array_key_exists($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $urls_for_redirect) ) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header('Location: http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$urls_for_redirect[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']]);
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function error_404() {
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

include '404.php';
exit;
}
```

самое простое средствами php. Но лучше делать совместно с .htaccess